# Scss function returns no calculated value

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I am working on a mixin for breakpoints and I have the following issue.
when a specific state (mode for max-width) is set then the breakpoint should be recalculated by extracting one em value (1px/16 (default font size)).

This is the important part of my code (I might get rid of the function, basically this can be done inline):

```
$mediaBreakpoint: map-get( $breakpoints, $breakpoint );

// if the mode is for max-width then subtract 1px.
@if map-get( $modes, $mode ) == 'max-width' {
    $mediaBreakpoint: calculateMaxWidth(#{$mediaBreakpoint})
}
@debug $mediaBreakpoint; 

/**
* calculate the max width based on input
*/
@function calculateMaxWidth($breakpoint){
    $newBreakpoint: calc( #{$breakpoint} - 0.0625em ); // 1px  in em sizing.
    @return $newBreakpoint;
}
```

But whatever I try, the @debug value shows as:
48em-0.0625em // this is invalid, I need the actual outcome (in this case 47.9375) .
64em  // valid min-width

This is the compiled css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: calc( 48em - 0.0625 )) {

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you use string interpolation on the parameter when calling your own function? here: `$mediaBreakpoint: calculateMaxWidth(#{$mediaBreakpoint})`. That is not necessairy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself after a lot of debugging. At first I misunderstood the interpolation. After reading the docs in depth I noticed that I should have wrapped the whole calculation instead of just the variable because I am working inside the map expression.

Quoted from the official Sass docs:

> Interpolation can be used almost anywhere in a Sass stylesheet to embed the result of a SassScript expression into a chunk of CSS.

I changed my function to calculate like this and then the mixin started working. hooray!

```
$newBreakpoint: #{$breakpoint - 0.0625em};
```